# How to find and merge some specific lines from one file B to another file A in linux with condition that lines in file B can be increase or decrease

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

### File A:

abc

bcd

def

ghi

jkl

### File B:

bcd

def

klm

### Desired output:

abc

bcd

def

klm

ghi

jkl

Comment: Well, you should show us what you have tried first rather than just expect us to do all the work for you. But just a point... the order of you output makes no sense. Wy would "klm" just appear in between "def" and "ghi"?

Answer (score 1):

Give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' fileA fileB > output
```

It works for your example files.

Comment: Hi, This works with out any issues. but if i need to keep abc and jkl in file A and only wants to replace the line between them with them with lines in file B. As the output of File b keeps on changing.

Comment: @Deepak sorry, I don't get you.

Answer (score 0):

`cat A B | sort -u` will remove the repeated ones and do sorts, @Kent 's anwser is more elegant, but still, the output doesn't satisfy your description.